# Good method for solving nCr and nPr

Tags: probability, complex-numbers, dynamic-programming

Okay, so I'm designing a calculator that accepts real and imaginary inputs, and I'm going to implement the nPr and nCr functions soon.

I already programmed in the factorial function, which also accepts real and imaginary input, thanks to the incredibly fast Lanczos approximation.

I know the nCr function can be computed by $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ and the nPr function can be computed by $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$, but this becomes a problem when n and r become very large integers.

OpenProcessing.org (where I'm programming the calculator) is able to process any number up to $2^{1024}$, and any number above that is registered as ∞ (which I don't mind, in fact as a number reaches the overflow limit, it does tend to act like ∞, so it's actually somewhat practical).

As a result, trying to use factorials to compute say, {$^{1000}_{997}$} would register as $\frac{∞}∞$.  This results in an error despite the true answer being 166,167,000, a number well within acceptable limits.

> **My question is this:** Is there an alternative method I can use when such values approach such large numbers.

And no, I cannot simply repeatedly multiply fractions since, as I've said before, this calculator needs to be able to accept noninteger arguments.

I already know of Sterlings approximation, and I don't think I'd find it very useful due to it being a finite formula, as opposed to a more preferred infinite summation, product, or repeated iteration of some function, preferably one that converges quickly.

Comment: Instead of using nPr as $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ you can write it instead as $n\frac{r}{~}$ using [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) notation.  That is to say, $n\frac{r}{~}=\underbrace{n(n-1)(n-2)\dots (n-r+1)}_{r~\text{terms}}$ and further write nCr as instead $\frac{n\frac{r}{~}}{r!}$ or as $\frac{n\frac{(n-r)}{~}}{(n-r)!}$ depending on which value is more manageable.  Of course, this would use a loop to calculate and would be more time consuming than lookup tables or stirling approximations, but will avoid some more of the overflow errors (not all).

Comment: Keep in mind, my suggestion only really makes sense with natural inputs, but then again I know of no useful interpretation to $\binom{u}{v}$ for arbitrary complex $u$ and $v$ that doesn't require the overuse of the gamma function.

Comment: Math:  re your original post, and the edit I made:  Can you see how much easier to follow your thought process than you wrote more than a dozen run on sentences?  You're welcome.

Comment: For $nCr$ you can alternate multiplications and divisions to keep the intermediate values manageable. In fact, every intermediate value will be an integer. It can also be helpful to take advantage of the symmetry of binomial coefficients.

Comment: What @amd means is the "good recursion" given in (http://penguin.ewu.edu/~trolfe/BinomialCoeff/index.html).

Comment: @amWhy , the entire question consists of $7$ sentences, after your edits. You appear to have fixed $2$ run-ons. I understand that you must have found this frustrating, but claiming that $2>12$ on a math website seems a bit sketchy. Also, your comment in which you complained about the OP's sentence structure is a mess of its own. "Can you see how much easier it is to follow your thought process than you wrote more than a dozen run on sentences?," is simply not a sentence. Let's be friendlier than that, anyway.

Comment: Have you considered using an algorithm for approximating the Gamma function? i.e. $\Gamma (n) = (n-1)!$. Not sure if this would help or not. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation